# Adding some bold text inside a text string passed as a prop to a component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a reusable component in React which I can pass a few very simple props to:

```
const Section1 = (props) => (
 <div className="section">
  <div className="container is-narrow">
    <div className="content is-medium"><h2 className="title is-1 is-bottom-bordered">{props.section1Title}</h2></div>
      <div className="columns">
        <div className="column is-half">
          <div className="content">
              <blockquote>{props.section1Blockquote}</blockquote> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="column is-half">
          <div className="content">
            <p>{props.section1Text}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I use this component I pass the props like this:

```
<Section1
  section1Title="Example title"
  section1Blockquote="Example blockquote"
  section1Text="Example text"
/>
```

Inside the strings that I pass as props, is it possible to style part of the text, making it bold? Not the entire string, just portion of it. In the example above, section1Blockquote, how can I make the word 'Example' bold?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should pass jsx to props so that you can use your own class or markup.

```
<Section1
  section1Title={<React.Fragment>Example <span className="bold">title</span></React.Fragment>}
  section1Blockquote="Example blockquote"
  section1Text="Example text"
/>
```

in your css file.

```
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

or you can use strong tag directly.

```
<Section1
  section1Title={<>Example <strong>title</strong></>}
  section1Blockquote="Example blockquote"
  section1Text="Example text"
/>
```

update: instead of wrapping inside any html tag(span) we can use React.Fragment( shorthand <>) which will not create extra element outside.

Comment: Instead of using <span> to wrap the jsx you could use the react fragment shorthand <> </> which reads a bit cleaner, and in some use cases can prevent unintended formatting issues. https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I was looking for.